# Using Applescript to switch VoiceOver language in osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript, accessibility

I am developing a multi-language OSX app which also uses text-to-speech.
I am using mac's VoiceOver and Applescript to control it.
In the app, users can switch languages and VoiceOver has to read the text in the selected language.

The goal is to switch VoiceOver language without quitting my application.
I can't find a way in Cocoa or Applescript to find out what is the current language in VoiceOver and to actively specify what language to set.

This is what I have done so far.

In VoiceOver Utility there is a section called Activities that lets you setup some VoiceOver configurations, including the language.
So I created an English and a French activity.
Then I found this really helpful list of commands that you can use in Applescript to control VoiceOver: http://www.cbtbc.org/tools/asvo/voec.php

In this list the only commands that control VoiceOver activities are: "*open activity chooser*"
and "*previous activity*"

"*previous activity*" changes the language, but there's no way to know what activity you are currently on or to specify the name of the activity that you want to go to (English or French) when the user presses the language button.
So for example, if the user clicks on the English button twice, or switches the app language when the VoiceOver is off, the application might be showing English text while the VoiceOver might be set in French.

Anybody had experience with this?
Thank you so much for your help!